# What is a good pattern for caching DOM values in React classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A common pattern we have evolved in our team over the years was to store DOM dimensions after a render so that we could access them later with less performance implications (as an example - figure out if a component should be rendered while scrolling through a large list). A basic example will be:

```
class List extends Component {
    construct(props){
        super(props)

        this.elements = {};
        this.heights = {};
    }

    render(){
        return <ol>
            {this.props.items.map((item,i)=>this.getItem(item,i))}
        </ol>;
    }

    getItem(item){
        return <li key={item.id} ref={(el)=>this.cacheElement(el, item.id)}>{item.name}</li>
    }

    cacheElement(el,id){
        this.elements[id] = findDOMNode(el);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.items.forEach(item=>{
            //in real examples this will probably implement some sort 
            //of memoization to prevent overpolling over existing values
            this.heights[item.id] = elements[item.id].offsetHieght;
        })
    }
}
```

*Note - I know that how I'm using refs here and storing DOM references is not ideal and that there might be other anti-patterns here - was aiming for code clarity*

Historically the reason we did not save this in the `setState` was because we did not want to force a re-render due to a post render calculation. However from reading around I learned this approach is sort of an anti-pattern - specifically that storing data outside of `setState` might not play nicely with the async rendering features that started trickling out in the last few months.

Are there other patterns for these kind of challenges (post render values that need to be cached for future use)?

Comment: Do you really think iterating over all elements at each rerender is performance wise?

Comment: No - I said I know the example is inefficient - was aiming for the point to be clear, not the example to be the most efficient it can be. Point was that I need to cache DOM positions for later use.